# DevExpress GridView PostEditor

Tags: c#, repository, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a grid control with unbound columns in it.
The question is, everytime I change a cell value (I am using a repository item) I immediately call the gridview.PostEditor() method so that it would right away update the grid data which requires to be updated everytime I change a specific cell. Keep in mind  that I am using the PostEditor() method so that I dont have to lose the focus on a cell first to update the gridview. Anyway, calling the PostEditor() will update my grid (which works fine) and still have the reposiroty item open, a repositoty item spin edit control to be exact, but the thing is if I hit a numeric key, It will discard the old value and replace it with the new one. I don't want it to behave like this. I want it so if the old value is 10.00 and I press the "0" key it will change the value to a "100.00" not back to "0.00".

Please help!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I understand the question. But I did a search on some of my personal devexpress stuff and found this:

```
private void riSpinEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextEdit edit = grdReceiveGoods.FocusedView.ActiveEditor as TextEdit;
            if (edit != null)
            {
                int len = edit.SelectionLength;
                int start = edit.SelectionStart;
                grdReceiveGoods.FocusedView.PostEditor();
                edit.SelectionLength = len;
                edit.SelectionStart = start;
            }
        }
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, This doesn't seem to be working. I am doing the same for a combo box edit. But edit.SelectionLength is not getting assigned to len. Any suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450553/devexpress-repository-comboboxedit-loosing-cursor-position-edit-selectionstart