# Devexpress Repository ComboBoxEdit loosing cursor position. Edit.SelectionStart Not being assigned

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I am having an issue with my comboBoxEdit in a gridcontrol. I am using Winforms Devepress 11.2. I clicked in the text of an existing Repository comboBoxEdit,  and typed in "appear backwards", however, it displayed as "sdrawkcab raeppa" like it would in a mirror.
There are some posts about this topic but none of the solutions seem to work

The reason for this is the following

```
 foreach (GridColumn column in this.gvNotes.Columns)
            {
                var columnEdit = column.ColumnEdit;
                if (columnEdit != null)
                {
                    column.ColumnEdit.EditValueChanged += this.PostEditValueChanged;

                }
            }
   private void PostEditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.gvNotes.PostEditor();

        }
```

This PostEditor ensures the save button is enabled when the user is still in the current cell. The user does not need to leave the cell or change column for the changes to be posted to the grid.

So this is what I did:

```
private void PostEditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxEdit edit = this.gridNotes.FocusedView.ActiveEditor as ComboBoxEdit;
            if (edit != null)
            {
                int len = edit.SelectionLength;
                int start = edit.SelectionStart;
                gridNotes.FocusedView.PostEditor();
                edit.SelectionLength = len;
                edit.SelectionStart = start;

            }
```

This did not solve the problem of the cursor resetting to the start position. Edit.SelectionStart is not being assinged to the len value.Even though len changes to 1 edit.SelectionStart remains at 0
Does anyone know what event needs to be handled to not loose the cursor position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and seemed to set the caret position

global:    private int carretPosition = 0;

```
 editvaluechanged handler

     SaveCaretPosition(editValue.ToString().Length);
                        this.gridView1.PostEditor();
                        this.gridView1.ShowEditor();
                        this.SetCaretPosition(this.gridView1.ActiveEditor as DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit);

 private void SaveCaretPosition(int position)
        {
            carretPosition = position;
        }

        private void SetCaretPosition(TextEdit edit)
        {
            edit.SelectionStart = carretPosition;
        }
```